# Eclipse TCP/IP Monitor size

Tags: eclipse, http, soap, ide, traffic-measurement

I am trying to analyse my SOAP messages using the Eclispe TCP/IP Monitor. However when I see a request there is for example written:

```
Request: localhost:8888
Size: 1075 (1472) bytes
```

The type of the monitor is HTTP.

**Question:**
What are these two size values? Why is there one in a bracket?

Comment: I would bet for Size: 1075 sent (1472 received) bytes but I am not posting it as answer because I am only guessing :)

Comment: @Mateusz: The received bytes are in another "window" so it cant be that